# how daily deals aggregators get data from different deals website?

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I was wondering how daily deals aggregators scrap data from different deals website? I have seen many deals website which does't provide API and RSS feeds, but still this aggregators scraps data out of them. 
here are some websites which i am referring to

http://www.thedealmap.com/

http://www.dealmandi.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the site doesn't provide any API or RSS feed, it's still possible to extract data from it "the old-school way" by querying the pages where the info is and extracting the data from the returned HTML.

In `Python` this could be done using [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) for querying pages and [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) or [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract the data from the HTML.  For bigger projects, try using the [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) framework, which provides everything to code complex spiders.

Comment: true but do they do this for complex websites also?? i have seen some websites which uses post for there communication

Comment: Yes, it's also possible for complex websites. For more examples, here is a [list of sites/companies](http://dev.scrapy.org/wiki/CompaniesUsingScrapy) which use `scrapy` to extract data from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

When I built LesserThan - http://lesserthan.com - I found that most APIs or RSS feeds are unpublished. Only after you signup for an affiliate account do they give you the URL of the RSS feed.